# "Cannot find symbol symbol : constructor ..." in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, syntax-error

I have a class defined as follows...

```
public class df {
    String dt;
    String datestring;

    public String df(String dtstring) throws Exception {
        dt=dtstring;
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date inpdate = formatter.parse(dt);
        datestring = formatter.format(inpdate);
        Date outpdate = formatter.parse(datestring);
        SimpleDateFormat newformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        datestring = newformatter.format(outpdate);
        return datestring;
    }
}
```

I create instances of this class as follows, where `rsnpos.getString(1)` contains a date in yyyy-MM-dd format (e.g. 2010-01-01)...

```
new df(rsnpos.getString(1))
```

During compilation, I am getting the following error...

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor df(java.lang.String)
location: class df
```

I don't understand why this is happening, as I have defined a constructor as shown in my code. Could someone please assist me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a constructor... (constructors have an *implicit* "return type", the type of the class). That has an *explicit* return type, and is thus not a constructor, but a normal method named `df`.

Thus it is invalid when used as `new df(...)`, which is exactly what the error message says. On the other hand, `new df().df("x")` would still "work" because of the default parameterless constructor and the *method* `String df(String)`.

Note the updates to change it into a constructor:

```
public class df 
{

  String dt;
  String datestring;
  // Remove return type (and keep matched name) to make it a constructor.
  public df(String dtstring) throws Exception
  {
    dt=dtstring;
    ...
    datestring = newformatter.format(outpdate);
    // Constructors cannot "return"
    // return datestring;
  }

}
```

Please work on variable names and naming conventions and mutability redux :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class df
     {
 String dt;
 String datestring;
 public df(String dtstring) throws Exception
        {
                dt=dtstring;
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date inpdate = formatter.parse(dt);
                datestring = formatter.format(inpdate);
                Date outpdate = formatter.parse(datestring);
                SimpleDateFormat newformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                datestring = newformatter.format(outpdate);
        }
    }
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html .